# Respond to Daylight Savings in iPhone

Tags: ios, datetime, timezone

I want to convert the current date into canada time.

It shows 1 hour late

For Eg

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a";
NSTimeZone *utc =[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC-08:00"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:utc];
NSString *timeStamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"Time %@ ",timeStamp);
```

This returns

2014-05-01 21:17 PM

But the current time in canada is

2014-05-01 22:17 PM

I think i have to respond to Daylight saving. So how to get the time considering the DST

DST information to canada
http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/canada/vancouver

**Answer:**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a";
NSTimeZone *utc =[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Vancouver"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:utc];
NSString *timeStamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: Canada covers several timezones. Be more specific. BTW - at the moment no part of Canada is at UTC-8. Western Canada (Pacific timezone) is currently at UTC-7.

Comment: Vancouver time zone. it is UTC-08:00  https://www.google.co.in/search?q=vancouver+time+zone&oq=vancouver+time+zone&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5806j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Comment: No, at the moment Vancouver is UTC-7 due to being on daylight saving time. In the winter it is UTC-8. See http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/canada/vancouver

Comment: Thanks for your information rmaddy. That helps. Anyhow instead of abbrevation i used Colin's idea.  timeZoneWithName:@"America/Vancouver". It works.

Comment: As developers we cannot know the exact day on which the daylightsaving is on for a place. So giving UTC-7 or UTC-8 depending on date with hardcode is bad. Just let Apple do the magic. Anyhow thanks Maddy :]

Comment: BTW - I was pointing out the discrepancy in the actual and expected output. Setting the timezone by name is certainly the proper solution to show the time properly regardless of the time of year for a specific location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying a UTC offset. Instead, you need to specify a timezone:

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"__your timezone here__"]];
```

You can get the list of supported timezones as follows:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]);
```

Comment: The OP's code is fine other than they chose UTC-8 instead of UTC-7.

Comment: No, it is not fine, it will only work for 6 months out of a year!

Comment: Thanks Colin. KnowTimeZoneNames Helped me. It gave me the timezone names. Which i chose @"America/Vancouver". Thanks for your answer

Comment: @maddy good point, I assumed DST was the required timezone, rather than Daylight Savings Time. I have updated the answer accordingly.